# How to use another promise in a function which returns a new promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I started learning Promises in JS and I am trying to replace my existing callback logic using promises.  I wrote a function which returns a new promise, and also uses a promise of a database instance to retrieve the data. However, i am not sure if i am doing it right. Here is the code snippet,

**usersService.js**

```
var getUsers = function(queryObject) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        dbConnection.find(queryObject)
          .then(function(result) {
              if (result.length > 0) {
                resolve(result)
              } else {
                resolve(errorMessage.invalidUser())
              }).catch(function(err) {
              reject(err)
            });
          })
    };
```

**usersRouter.js**

```
router.get('/users', function (req,res,next) {
     var queryObject = { "userId":req.query.userId };
     userService.getUsers(queryObject)
          .then(function (data) { //some logic })
          .catch(function (err) { //some logic });
});
```

1. Can i use `resolve` conditionally ?
2. If the answer is **No**, what is the right       approach ?
3. Also, am i using the promise in a right manner, in the router?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a typo: `resovle(result)`

Comment: @melpomene edited

Comment: It's kind of unexpected to `resolve(errorMessage.invalidUser())`. You probably want to `reject(errorMessage.invalidUser())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dbConnection.find returns a promise, you can return it directly and choose what will be pass when you will resolve it. No need to wrap it inside an other promise.

```
var getUsers = function (queryObject) {
    return dbConnection.find(queryObject).then(function (result) {
       if (result.length > 0) {
          return result
       } else {
          return errorMessage.invalidUser()
       }
    })
};
```

Comment: What if i get any exception while talking to db? I mean to say, how can I leverage the catch block (of dbConnection)? Do i need to write another return statement in catch block and then check if the returned value is an instance or error in my the router?

Comment: for me it's better to catch error at then end, but I guess it depends on what you want to accomplish. You're allready catching errors in router so it's fine

Comment: The error in else condition is for incorrect userId, where the no. of search results are zero. I was asking about the errors thrown by dbConnection promise itself.

Comment: if dbConnection.find throw an error, you will received the error in  ```userService.getUsers(queryObject).catch(function (err) { //some logic });``` promises are chainable so you will received all errors in catch, no need to catch multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @Gatsbill . I will go ahead and test it this way!